# Find what version of specific perl packages available per ubuntu release

Tags: package-management, perl

I'm in need of knowing what module version a certain **perl** package (e.g. Net::Cmd)  is available in different Ubuntu versions.  I'm currently on 16.04 and need a later version of Net::Cmd to resolve (hopefully) an issue we are having in our OTRS implementation.

Short of installing the version is there a way to determine what the version would be for the later versions of Ubuntu?  Say 17.04? I'm not opposed to moving to a later version of Ubuntu.

Am I correct in thinking this is a system dependent perl package and therefore is one that should be be update on it's own?

Comment: I suppose this answers your question: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/perl

Comment: Not finding exactly what I'm looking for in https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/perl - maybe not drilling down to the correct spot?

Comment: https://packages.ubuntu.com/